# Add row in Table View from Search bar view controller to Other view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

Is it possible to add data coming from search bar present view controller to Zone View controller.

when I hit search bar a present view controller appear after that I select desired cell selected it disappear and data passes from present view controller to zone view controller.

Here is search bar Present view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CellForShowAllTVC

        print("Did Select call ***********")


        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Rider", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourzoneVC") as! YourZoneVC

vc.arryOfCityName.append(arryOfCity[indexPath.row]) //Pass array to zone View Controller but its not worked

 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)



    }
```

Here is Zone View controller

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        print(arryOfCityName)

        yourZonTV.reloadData()
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return arryOfCityName.count 

    }
//But its show data coming from search bar

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Rider", bundle: nil)

Cell3ForYourZone
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "zoneinmapviewVC") as! ZoneInMapViewVC

        vc.getCityCompare1 = arryOfCityName[indexPath.row] as? String

        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: The first snippet makes no sense at all. `let cell = ...` is pointless and `vc` is instantiated and then being thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you pass data you created a new one.
You can use delegates

And don't create a new viewController

Example code below:

```
protocol AViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
  func aViewController(add item: <#YourObject#>)
}

final class AViewController: UIViewController {

  weak var delegate: AViewControllerDelegate?

  lazy var bViewController: BViewController  = {
    // UIStoryboard...
    let controller = BViewController()
    self.delegate = controller
    return controller
  }()

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    delegate?.aViewController(add: <#YourObject#>)
  }
}


final class BViewController: UIViewController {


}
extension BViewController: AViewControllerDelegate {

  func aViewController(add item: <#YourObject#>) {
    // add and reload data
  }
}
```